# How to substitute a character in multiples locations with R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I'm trying to split a dataframe with "," separators. However, some parts of the strings have the pattern [0-9][,][0-9]{2}, and i'd like to substitute only the comma inside, not the hole pattern, in order to preserve the numerical inputs.
I try to solve with stringr, but got stucked in the following pattern of error:

```
library(stringr)
string <- '"name: John","age: 27","height: 1,73", "weight: 78,30"'
str_replace_all(string, "[0-9][,][0-9]{2}", "[0-9][;][0-9]{2}")
[1] "\"name: John\",\"age: 27\",\"height: [0-9][;][0-9]{2}\", \"weight: 7[0-9][;][0-9]{2}\""
```

I know it can be done with substitution by position, but the string is too big.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `str_replace_all(string, "([0-9]),([0-9]{2})", "\\1;\\2")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capturing groups around the parts of the pattern you need to keep and, in the replacement pattern, refer to those submatches with backreferences:

```
> str_replace_all(string, "([0-9]),([0-9]{2})", "\\1;\\2")
[1] "\"name: John\",\"age: 27\",\"height: 1;73\", \"weight: 78;30\""
```

Or the same regex can be used with `gsub`:

```
> gsub("([0-9]),([0-9]{2})", "\\1;\\2", string)
[1] "\"name: John\",\"age: 27\",\"height: 1;73\", \"weight: 78;30\""
```

**Details**:

- `([0-9])` - capturing group 1, whose value is referred to using `\\1` in the replacement pattern, matching a single digit
- `,` - a comma
- `([0-9]{2})` - capturing group 2, whose value is referred to using `\\2` in the replacement pattern, matching 2 digits.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wiktor. However, do you know how i can apply this gsub in all lines of a big dataset? The function works well in single line, but doesn't do the job when applied to the whole dataset....

Comment: gsub should do the job if you provide a vector or a data frame column as input.